# Fetch .catch error message is not playing even though I get a code on console.log

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, error-handling, alert

I'm suppose to text to make sure my code response to an error. My code requires the user to type in a dog breed out of a list. if they type in something not on the list it results in an error. I get the error in the console, but for some reason the .catch doesn't play out.

In my javascript code I get a message that 'error is declared but it's value is never read'

```
function arrayAPI(breed){
    console.log("arrayAPI ran");

    let breedLink = "https://dog.ceo/api/breed/hound/" + breed + "/images/random"; 

   console.log("breedLink: " + breedLink)


        fetch(breedLink)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJSON => getDogImage(responseJSON))
        .catch(error => alert('error! danger!'));

}
```

Comment: *"In my javascript code I get a message that 'error is declared but it's value is never read'"* That's not coming from JavaScript, it's from a lint-style tool.

Comment: If the load fails, I can't see any reason that `alert` wouldn't run.

Comment: Side note (it's not the problem): You're missing out a check of the `ok` property in the first `then` handler. Details in [this post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog. It's a footgun in the `fetch` API.

Comment: What error do you get in console?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()